# how to use sidr with webpack?

Tags: jquery, webpack, sidr

I'm learning webpack, and want to import sidr into my project.
how should I do this right?
I've tried:

```
import sidr from 'sidr';
```

but it Cannot find module "sidr"

I tried to add

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  'jQuery': 'jquery',
  '$': 'jquery',
  'global.jQuery': 'jquery'
})
...
alias: {
      // sidr: 'sidr/src/jquery.sidr.js',
      sidr: 'sidr/src/js/sidr',
    }
```

after this it can find, but then fails on

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (execute) [./~/sidr/src/js/sidr.js:1,0]
```

also, how to initiate sidr if it could be imported to my es6 main file?